# HERE Maps: Default initial size for MapDataPrefetcher in Android SDK

Tags: android, here-api

Is there an initial default size when first using the MapDataPrefetcher in HERE Maps?

On startup, I cleared my map data cache and within the `PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener()` function.
I created a `GeoBoundingBox` with a size of `100m x 100m` centred in my current position.

The estimated map size when fetching this was about `15MB`. Then, I repeated this process with a GeoBoundingBox of `10,000m x 10,000m` and when fetching this map area the size was only `16MB`.

With the `100sqm` box I moved outside of this range (I was driving) for a few kilometers or so, but there was no new map data fetched, but the detail I required (road names and speed limits) was returned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Map data can be fetched into a persistent cache (with default size of 256 MB) to enable offline map capabilities by specifying a bounding box or radius around a route. This can be done through the MapDataPrefetcher and associated classes. The MapDataPrefetcher provides a set of methods to estimate the size of fetches (in KB), initiate fetches, cancel fetches, and clear the map data cache.

To check for the size of the data in advance use estimateMapDataSize(GeoBoundingBox) or estimateMapDataSize(Route, int) methods:

GeoBoundingBox bbox = ...
MapDataPrefetcher.Request request =
MapDataPrefetcher.getInstance( ).estimateMapDataSize(bbox);
...